# How to set a collection-property with FKs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a `Business` and a `Category` model.

Each `Business` has many `Categories` via an exposed collection (`Category` is disregarding the `Business` entity).

Now here is my controller-action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
private ActionResult Save(Business business)
{
  //Context is a lazy-loaded property that returns a reference to the DbContext
  //It's disposal is taken care of at the controller's Dispose override.
  foreach (var category in business.Categories)
   Context.Categories.Attach(category);

  if (business.BusinessId > 0)
   Context.Businesses.Attach(business);
  else
   Context.Businesses.Add(business);

   Context.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now there are several `business.Categories` that have their `CategoryId` set to an existing `Category` (the `Title` property of `Category` is missing tho).

After hitting `SaveChanges` and reloading the `Business` from server, the `Categories` are not there.

So my question is what's the proper way to set `Business.Categories` with a given array of existing `CategoryId`s.

When create a new `Business` however, the following `DbUpdateException` exception is thrown when calling `SaveChanges`:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Inner exception (`OptimisticConcurrencyException`):

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

### Update

after answer, here's the update code:

```
var storeBusiness = IncludeChildren().SingleOrDefault(b => b.BusinessId == business.BusinessId);
var entry = Context.Entry(storeBusiness);
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(business);
//storeBusiness.Categories.Clear();

foreach (var category in business.Categories)
{
  Context.Categories.Attach(category);
  storeBusiness.Categories.Add(category);
}
```

When calling `SaveChanges`, I'm getting the following `DbUpdateException`:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Here's how the Business/Category models look like:

```
public class Business
{
  public int BusinessId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(64)]
  [Display(Name = "Company name")]
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }

  public virtual BusinessType BusinessType { get; set; }

  private ICollection<Category> _Categories;
  public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories
  {
    get
    {
      return _Categories ?? (_Categories = new HashSet<Category>());
    }
    set
    {
      _Categories = value;
    }
  }

  private ICollection<Branch> _Branches;
  public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches
  {
    get
    {
      return _Branches ?? (_Branches = new HashSet<Branch>());
    }
    set
    {
      _Branches = value;
    }
  }
}

public class Category
{
  [Key]
  public int CategoryId { get; set; }

  [Unique]
  [Required]
  [MaxLength(32)]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public string Description { get; set; }

  public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Parent category")]
  [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
  public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

  private ICollection<Category> _Children;
  public virtual ICollection<Category> Children
  {
    get
    {
      return _Children ?? (_Children = new HashSet<Category>());
    }
    set
    {
      _Children = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Just to make it clear again, the `Category` I'm attaching to existing/new `Business`es already exist in the DB and have an ID, which is what I'm using to attach it with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I treat the two cases - updating an existing business and adding a new business - separately because the two problems you mentioned have different reasons.

#### Updating an existing Business entity

That's the `if` case (`if (business.BusinessId > 0)`) in your example. It is clear that nothing happens here and no change will be stored to the database because you are just attaching the `Category` objects and the `Business` entity and then call `SaveChanges`. Attaching means that the entities are added to the context in state `Unchanged` and for entities that are in that state EF won't send any command to the database at all.

If you want to update a detached object graph - `Business` plus collection of `Category` entities in your case - you generally have the problem that a collection item could have been removed from the collection and an item could have been added - compared to the current state stored in the database. It might be also possible that a collection item's properties  and that the parent entity `Business` have been modified. Unless you have tracked all changes manually while the object graph was detached - i.e. EF itself could not track the changes - which is difficult in a web application because you had to do this in the browser UI, your only chance to perform a correct UPDATE of the whole object graph is comparing it with the current state in the database and then put the objects into the correct state `Added`, `Deleted` and `Modified` (and perhaps `Unchanged` for some of them).

So, the procedure is to load the `Business` including its current `Categories` from the database and then merge the changes of the detached graph into the loaded (=attached) graph. It could look like this:

```
private ActionResult Save(Business business)
{
    if (business.BusinessId > 0) // = business exists
    {
        var businessInDb = Context.Businesses
            .Include(b => b.Categories)
            .Single(b => b.BusinessId == business.BusinessId);

        // Update parent properties (only the scalar properties)
        Context.Entry(businessInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(business);

        // Delete relationship to category if the relationship exists in the DB
        // but has been removed in the UI
        foreach (var categoryInDb in businessInDb.Categories.ToList())
        {
            if (!business.Categories.Any(c =>
                c.CategoryId == categoryInDb.CategoryId))
                businessInDb.Categories.Remove(categoryInDb);
        }

        // Add relationship to category if the relationship doesn't exist
        // in the DB but has been added in the UI
        foreach (var category in business.Categories)
        {
            var categoryInDb = businessInDb.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c =>
                c.CategoryId == category.CategoryId)

            if (categoryInDb == null)
            {
                Context.Categories.Attach(category);
                businessInDb.Categories.Add(category);
            }
            // no else case here because I assume that categories couldn't have
            // have been modified in the UI, otherwise the else case would be:
            // else
            //   Context.Entry(categoryInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(category);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // see below
    }
    Context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

#### Adding a new Business entity

Your procedure to add a new `Business` together with its related `Categories` is correct. Just attach all `Categories` as existing entities to the context and then add the new `Business` to the context:

```
foreach (var category in business.Categories)
    Context.Categories.Attach(category);
Context.Businesses.Add(business);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

If all `Categories` you are attaching really have a key value that exists in the database this should work without exception.

Your exception means that at least one of the `Categories` has an invalid key value (i.e. it does not exist in the database). Maybe it has been deleted in the meantime from the DB or because it is not correctly posted back from the Web UI.

In case of an independent association - that is an association without FK property `BusinessId` in `Category` - you get indeed this `OptimisticConcurrencyException`. (EF seems to assume here that the category has been deleted from the DB by another user.) In case of a foreign key association - that is an association which has a FK property `BusinessId` in `Category` - you would get an exception about a foreign key constraint violation.

If you want to avoid this exception - and if it occurs in fact because another user deleted a `Category`, not because the `Category` is empty/`0` since it doesn't get posted back to the server (fix this with a hidden input field instead) - you better load the categories by `CategoryId` (`Find`) from the database instead of attaching them and if one doesn't exist anymore ignore it and remove it from the `business.Categories` collection (or redirect to an error page to inform the user or something like that).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding part 1, does calling `SetValues` of `ObjectStateEntry` update the inner properties (i.e. `Categories`?), and I'm asking because the graph is huge! Besides the categories are never supposed to be edited in this page. I just want to replace the old categories with the new ones, disregarding the old ones.

Comment: @Shimmy: No, `SetValues` only updates the scalar properties of `Business`, not the navigation properties. What do you mean exactly with "*replace the old categories with the new ones*"? My understanding was (for the Update case): You load a business and the categories. Then the user can assign other (but existing) categories to the business (check box?) or unassign categories from the business (uncheck the check box?). Is this right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly this. I want to set the categories to the current checkboxes, I don't care what was before, the previous cats should be erased.

Comment: Actually according to what I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx), when set an entity's state to `Modified`, all the properties are updated. The question is if that does apply to referential properties as well, does it?

Comment: @Shimmy: No, it doesn't. For your scenario the code above or a similar one is needed. I know this is long code (gets shorter if you remove the comments :)) and more complex than it should be but the lack of good support for updating detached graphs is one of EF's big minus point. Its improvement is requested here (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864) but still not to expect in EF 6. You can also try the library of Brent McKendrick linked in the work item (I didn't try it myself) that claims to support this.

Comment: That library could have been great, but I'm having [issues](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/issues/5) with it. I guess I'll have to pollute my code with the entire graph, BTW, see [link](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/issues/5) for my full graph.

Comment: @Shimmy: Is the inner exception still the `OptimisticConcurrencyException`? Did you check in the debugger that the `CategoryID` values in the `business.Categories` collection are really valid? What about `ParentCategoryId`? Is it `null` in all categories? If not, does it refer to a valid category?

Comment: you're right about the inner exception. However, the attached `Category` has its `ParentCategoryId` is null (I only selected one entry).

Comment: @Shimmy: And the `CategoryID` values in the `business.Categories` collection? For me it's still the most likely reason for the exception that the `CategoryID` does not refer to a existing category in the DB. Is `Category.Children` empty or `null`?

Comment: But why do I have to care about the properties? As soon as the state is `Unchanged`, and the PK exists (it does for sure), it shouldn't even bother comparing the old properties. All I want is attach the `Category` PK to `Business` FK. Besides, I compared the properties and it's equal. Can you think of something else?

Comment: @Shimmy: You could try to inspect the SQL statement that is sent when calling `SaveChanges` with a profiler. The UPDATE statement will have a WHERE clause. The exception means that this WHERE clause has 0 hits. Perhaps the WHERE clause and the values of its parameters give an indication what is wrong or missing.

Comment: Can you please help me I'm trying to fix the issue in the GraphDiff library, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450383/exception-in-expression-trees

Comment: @Shimmy: Sorry, I can't help here, it is beyond my knowledge about the Expression API.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception as well.
The problem with me was that the primary key of the added object was not being set by ADO Entity Framework. This resulted in the problem that the foreign key of the added object in the database could not be set as well.

I solved this problem by making sure the primary key was being set by the database itself.
If you're using SQL Server you can do that by adding the IDENTITY keyword with the column declaration in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my scenario, the PK is 100% set.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exception on a field I was trying to set beyond its MaxLength attribute. The field also had a Required attribute.  I'm working against an Oracle back-end database.  It wasn't until I increased the length did I finally get a descriptive error message from the underlying database engine that the length was too long. I suspect the foreign key related error message vaguely means that not all relationships could be updated because one of the inserts failed and didn't get their Key updated.